# Is God a solipsist?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-religion, omniscience

If you accept God: omnipotent, omniscient, eternally omnipresent.

Solipsist: Nothing outside the mind should be believed to exist. If one's own mind is the sum total of existence, then all perceived experience and existential things(i.e. the universe) are all merely internal processes of the mind.

So, does that make God a solipsist?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism

Comment: No. On most Abrahamic conceptions, [God is transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_(religion)) to the world he creates. Hence the created world is outside of his mind. Omnipotence already implies the possibility of such an outside, so an omnipotent being is not solipsistic.

Comment: Following my line of reasoning, if we identify God with every possible state of the world to sound like the Wittgenstein from the Tractatus, then there is no way around God (in a pantheistic sense) being a solipsist, yes?

Comment: It is unclear that God "in a pantheistic sense" even has a "mind", or that permeation of everything amounts to "nothing outside", so no. And I suspect that according to Wittgenstein this sort of  manipulation of words "God" and "solipsism" (beyond the uses that establish their meaning) qualifies as nonsense/empty language.

Comment: "It is unclear that God "in a pantheistic sense" even has a "mind", or that permeation of everything amounts to "nothing outside", so no."                                      I'm not sure about this. It seems to me that in a pantheistic universe the only "true" mind is that of "G"od.

Comment: Or God=Nature and has no mind at all. "Pantheism" is a very broad label, and divinity need not be modeled on worn out anthropomorphic stereotypes. Even if he does have it, and permeates the universe like water sponge, it does not mean that there is nothing in the sponge besides the water. And, being omnipotent, he can surely make some of that.

Comment: @Conifold I don't think we have sufficient cause to conclude "...the created world is outside of his mind." But for the same token _if_ we are inside, then there may be an outside of his mind that are sufficiently differentiated from god (of this universe) to escape solipsism.

Comment: Regardless  my comment to Conifold, or that I can find no _communicable_ supporting argument, I'd say yes E is. But contemplating this is like looking at the the dirt beneath the flowers.

Comment: @christo183 We have no sufficient cause to conclude anything, which is why this particular wordplay gets old fast. If one really wants a solipsistic God [Berkeley's](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/berkeley/#3.1.3) is probably the closest, but he is neither pantheistic nor particularly popular.

Answer (score 2):

**As so posed, the answer would be "yes" according to some conceptions of God, and "no" according to some other conceptions of God:**

- **If you are a pantheist** --believing that God is the totality of everything in the universe --or (like me) a [panentheist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panentheism), believing that the totality of the universe is contained within God, then *by definition*, an omniscient God would know (not just believe) that everything is within the mind of God.  This is essentially the position of ideal monists like [Bishop Berkeley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Berkeley).
- On the other hand, **in many religious and philosophical traditions, God is viewed as creating a material universe that exists outside of God**.  This is arguably [what is taught](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+1&version=NIV) in the standard Judeo-Christian tradition.  Similarly, while most of Plato's work suggests he is properly considered an Idealist, his myth of the [demiurge](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Demiurge) (*Timaeus*) speaks of a creator god (or demigod) that creates a material world in imitation of the ideal but not *of a substance* with the ideal.  Likewise, in [Deism](https://www.allaboutphilosophy.org/deism.htm), God is distinguished from Creation (and also distanced and arguably estranged from it). Finally, if you do not believe God is personified, then it does not make sense to speak of God's "beliefs" at all.  God would not fit your description in any of those conceptions.

It's further worth noting that **solipsism is generally considered a delusion**.  If I am but a limited mortal part of the universe, and yet I believe all of the universe is contained within me, that is a solipsistic delusion.  On the other hand, if God contains the universe, and knows God's self to contain the universe, then that is neither a delusion nor a mere belief.  (By analogy --if I believe myself to be the Pope, that is a delusion.  But the fact of believing oneself to be Pope is not intrinsically delusive.  If Pope Francis believes it, he is perfectly correct.)

Comment: P.M.S. Hacker talks about this: What the solipsist means, and is correct in thinking, is that the world and life are one, that man is the microcosm, that I am my world. These equations... express a doctrine which I shall call Transcendental Solipsism. They involve a belief in the transcendental ideality of time. ... Wittgenstein thought that his transcendental idealist doctrines, though profoundly important, are literally inexpressible.

— Hacker, Insight and Illusion, op cit., n. 3, pp. 99-100.

Answer (score 0):

The likely answer is yes. This is because if we say God created something outside then we are assuming God has a location in relation to what he has created. This involves assuming that God is in space, time and relativity.

There could be nothing outside God because space and time do not apply to God they apply to creatures. Terms like space, time and causation are relative and apply to creatures but not God who is absolute.

We cannot rely on traditional religious interpretations because many of these interpretations were literal based on concrete thinking and projected God as a man in the sky or as having a human personality, which was the form that could be readily understood and related to at the time.[edited 12/05/22 for better clarity].

Nothing exists other than God. If this was not true then there is a separation, form, time, space.. relative terms again, which do not apply to God.

Where is creation then? It is in the mind of God. Like we create characters and stories and worlds in our minds which we then express in the outside world, God creates and holds infinite universes in His mind but there is nothing outside him to express it in. It is all expressed within. (That doesn't lead to determinism by the way). [Edited 12/05/22 for better clarity]

It is very difficult to think of God without making worldly assumptions, without projecting what we know onto what we do not know.

I have based my propositional thoughts on reflections on mystical readings. A good source is Ibn Arabi, Hermes Trismegistus and the Kybalion.

Comment: -1: Christian and Islamic theology place God outside of time and space. He does not have a 'location' as you put it. It is Epicurean thinking that suggested that traditional religons anthropised natural things. But a close reading of scripture shows that they did no such things. Theology views such anthropomorpgisms as symbolic because the finite human mind cannot fathom divine things directly. This is taken literally in Buddhism, which the Vatican says has taken the *Via Negativa* to the question of God.

Comment: Text edited dated 12/05/22 for better clarification

Answer (score -1):

I would say yes, and that this is why solipsism is unfalsifiable.

EDIT 1: A study of mysticism and the mystical theology would seem the obvious place to go for an exploration of this idea. Perhaps Kant and his 'mind-in-general' as the source of space-time is also relevant.

EDIT: This is a poor answer and deserves the down-votes. I couldn't see how to answer the OP with anything less than a long essay and still can't. As Chris says above, it's a question all about definitions.

I was just noting that if God is a solipsist then this would explain the unfalsifiablity of solipsism. This seems to me an important and suggestive philosophical fact.

Comment: I think this needs more justification, perhaps a reference to others who take a similar position on solipsism being unfalsifiable and God being a solipsist. Providing references is an opportunity, that should not be missed, to guide the reader's future exploration of the topic.

Comment: @FrankHubeny - Quite right. I was musing out loud. I added a sentence.

Comment: I did not down vote, but I did vote to delete when it appeared in the review queue. Best wishes.